# Xamarin IOS base UiViewController

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am developing an `IOS` application and have a lot of code that I plan to reuse in a lot of UiViewControllers.  Because of this i want to have :

```
BaseController : UIViewController

NewController : BaseController
```

So that any code i put in the `BaseController` can be reused in any controller that extends from it.

The code runs for this, except that the NewController's `xib` does not show up, rather the BaseController's xib shows up (a blank screen).

What i want is a way to remove the `xib` from basecontroller or find a way for the newcontrollers xib to be shown.

Comment: Do you need your BaseController's XIB?

Comment: No I don't, if its possible to create a controller without a xib associated with it that's fine too.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to to have a .XIB associated with a UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Using a Xib in child code (NewController)

```
public partial class NewController : BaseController
{


    public NewController () : base ("YourXibName", null)
    {}

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
         base.ViewDidLoad ();

(...)
```

And your BaseController would be:

```
public partial class BaseController : UIViewController
{

    public BaseController (string nibName, NSBundle bundle) : base (nibName, bundle)
    {}

    (...)
```